# tkinter not printing until the window is closed

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here is a minimal example in which left-cliking with the mouse creates a popup window with several choices. Upon selection, the popup is destroyed and the selection is printed.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Interface(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.can = tk.Canvas(self,background="green",width = 500, height = 500)
        self.can.pack()
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.choice)

    def choice(self, event):
        popup = tk.Toplevel()
        popup.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
        var = tk.IntVar()
        tk.Radiobutton(popup, text="Zero", value=0, variable=var, indicator=0).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(popup, text="0ne", value=1, variable=var, indicator=0).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(popup, text="Confirm", fg="red", indicator=0,
                       command=lambda:popup.destroy()).pack()
        popup.mainloop()
        print("choice:", var.get())

main = Interface()
main.mainloop()
```

It almost works, however it is only printed *after* the main window is closed.
In addition I don't understand why some of the buttons seem already selected.

[Python 3.7, Windows 10]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure why your code doesn't work, but think it's got something to do with there effectively being two `mainloop()`s running — one "nested" inside the the other — so ending the inner one isn't allowing the next line in the `choice()` method to execute until the outer one for the main window also ends.

Regardless of whether that explanation is true or not, a way to workaround the issue is to define the callback function separately to make it easy to put multiple statements in it, then put both the popup `destroy()` and the `print()` call in that:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Interface(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.can = tk.Canvas(self, background="green", width=500, height=500)
        self.can.pack()
        self.bind('<Button-1>', self.choice)

    def choice(self, event):
        popup = tk.Toplevel()
        popup.attributes('-topmost', 'true')
        var = tk.IntVar()

        def callback():
            popup.destroy()
            print("choice:", var.get())

        tk.Radiobutton(popup, text="Zero", value=0, variable=var, indicator=0).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(popup, text="0ne", value=1, variable=var, indicator=0).pack()
        tk.Radiobutton(popup, text="Confirm", fg="red", indicator=0,
                       command=callback).pack()
        popup.mainloop()


main = Interface()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works fine. Since you suggested the problem comes from having two `mainloop()` running, I found out that I could replace `popup.mainloop()` by `popup.transient(self)  # popup cannot be minimized`
      `popup.grab_set()  # user cannot interact with main window`
        `self.wait_window(popup)  # Pauses the main window`

Comment: Eman: I can why that would work. NOte that in the code in my answer you don't need to make the call to `popup.mainloop()` at all in `choice()`. Just leaving it out doesn't place all the restrictions that your approach does however.